# Stable Cohomotopy as $K \mathbb{F}_1$

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, stable-homotopy

Various classical results suggest that [stable cohomotopy](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable%20cohomotopy) may usefully be regarded as being the algebraic K-theory over the "field with one element" $\mathbb{F}_1$:

$$
  K \mathbb{F}_1 \;\simeq\; \mathbb{S}
$$

A summary table with pointers is on the nLab [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/print/Segal%20completion%20--%20table).

Guillot has made this observation the starting point in his study of "Adams operations in cohomotopy" ([arXiv:math/0612327](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612327)), on which Jack Morava then based his note "Power operations and Absolute Geometry" (2012, [pdf](http://www.lemiller.net/media/slidesconf/AbsolutePower.pdf)). Both of these seem to remain unpublished, though.

Has anyone picked this up? Are there any further developments along these lines?

Answer (score 4):

Every symmetric monoidal category has a $K$-theory spectrum, and the $K$-theory spectrum of the category of finite sets and bijections is just the sphere spectrum.  I believe that everything that you have mentioned can be done in a well-defined way form this point of view, without needing to refer to $\mathbb{F}_1$.  I think that Stefan Schwede has written about $\beta$-rings in these terms, although I do not remember where.  You pointed to a page on the nLab involving the Atiyah-Segal completion theorem and related things.  As these can be formulated uniformly for a large class of groups $G$, it is best to discuss them in the context of global stable homotopy theory, which is another body of work of Schwede.  I am not sure whether he has tied these things together.

Comment: Right, one does not need to mention F_1, one may just be content with Segal's theorem https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K-theory%20of%20a%20permutative%20category#StableCohomotopyIsKTheoryOfFinSet that S=K(FinSet). But it is suggestive to combine this with "K(FinSet)=K(F_1 Mod)". My question (maybe a "soft" question) is whether this suggestive picture has led anywhere further, beyond what Guillot & Morava indicated a few years back.